# Controllers disconnecting from console

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

I had disconnecting issues the day I set up my console. I went through all the possible solutions posted on the Xbox website, but none of them worked. So, I started using the controller with a wired connection and it worked fine.

I ordered another controller with a play and charge kit, but that controller and battery pack had no effect on the connection stability. I tried the battery pack in my first controller and that did not work either.

I think something to note is that my Xbox was on the floor or only a couple of feet off the ground for all the wireless connection attempts. Is placing the console higher a possible fix for this problem?

Comment: The original Xbox doesn't have wireless controllers. Please use the correct tag (xbox-360 or xbox-one) to clarify which console this is.

Comment: Also, this sounds like a hardware problem. Is returning the console an option?

Comment: Sorry, did not realize my error. I am new to Stack Exchange.Thanks for the tip. I'd rather not return the console since that is a bit of a hassle and because I am able to use it with a wired connection. Initially, it was an annoyance, but now it's more of a convenience thing if I can get the wireless connection working properly.

Answer (score -2):

if you are having problems with [xbox one controller](https://appuals.com/fix-xbox-one-controller-disconnecting/) the problems that you have stated such as Xbox was on the floor or only a couple of feet off the ground should not be the reasons. For starters try re-pairing your controller. You can do this by turning off your controller and then press the Sync button on the wireless dongle for Xbox One controllers connected to your computer. Now turn your Xbox One controller on, and quickly press the Sync button on it before it automatically turns off. Now wait for the controller to be re-paired. This should solve your problem that you have stated but if it's still not functioning as desired then this is most probably the hardware problem.

Comment: Flagged as spam; we've seen a wave of links to this website on Stack Overflow and Super User a few days ago. Apparently this one went undetected ...

Comment: @Glorfindel: That's because it was posted a full year ago.